# Cross tabulation of two variables with resulting average and SD

Tags: r, standard-deviation, mean, tables

I am beginner of R software. I am looking for two variables and result cross tabulated but not in the form of frequencies. Could I get help on how to get result as average and standard deviation instead of frequencies while cross tabulating in R.
my data looks like this

```
Treatment   Stage   Chlorophyll
Salt        Green   0.2
Salt        Green   0.3
Salt        Green   0.4
Salt        Pink    0.5
Salt        Pink    0.3
Salt        Pink    0.2
Salt        Red     0.5
Salt        Red     0.6
Salt        Red     0.7
Nitrogen    Green   0.4
Nitrogen    Green   0.6
Nitrogen    Green   0.9
Nitrogen    Pink    0.2
Nitrogen    Pink    0.3
Nitrogen    Pink    0.5
Nitrogen    Red     0.4
Nitrogen    Red     0.2
Nitrogen    Red     0.3
Control     Green   0.5
Control     Green   0.6
Control     Green   0.8
Control     Pink    0.5
Control     Pink    0.4
Control     Pink    0.6
Control     Red     0.2
Control     Red     0.3
Control     Red     0.1
```

I appreciate help from this community.

Comment: Welcome to CV. I edited your post so the data are readable. To set off text like that, make en empty li8ne, and put 4 spaces before each line. Then it comes out with the gray background and monospace font.

Comment: Thanks Russ for editing my data and the valuable comment on how to post.

Answer (score 6):

If your data is in a data frame called, say `Chlordata`, you can do:

```
 with(Chlordata, tapply(Chlorophyll, list(Treatment=Treatment,Stage=Stage), mean) )
```

to get a table of means:

```
          Stage
Treatment      Green      Pink Red
  Control  0.6333333 0.5000000 0.2
  Nitrogen 0.6333333 0.3333333 0.3
  Salt     0.3000000 0.3333333 0.6
```

and similarly

```
 with(Chlordata, tapply(Chlorophyll, list(Treatment=Treatment,Stage=Stage), sd) )
```

to get a table of standard deviations:

```
          Stage
Treatment      Green      Pink Red
  Control  0.1527525 0.1000000 0.1
  Nitrogen 0.2516611 0.1527525 0.1
  Salt     0.1000000 0.1527525 0.1
```

You might also want to investigate `xtabs`, for example, you could do something like this:

```
nn=xtabs(~Treatment+Stage,Chlordata)
xtabs(Chlorophyll~Treatment+Stage,Chlordata)/nn
```

to get a table of means.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b absolutely well result, just what I wanted! Could I bother you to get some idea on how to do mean comparison with same data while conducting a two way ANOVA. I am really looking for other test than TukeyHSD. I really want a group comparison of mean than pair wise comparison, like treatment, stage and treatment X stage mean comparison. Thanks Again.

Comment: That sounds like an entirely new question; but you should search on the keywords in case it's already answered. For questions related to the statistical side, you'll likely find answers here. For questions more like "how do I do this in R?", it's probably nearer to on topic for stackoverflow.com. Search one or both and if your question hasn't already been answered, post to whichever one is best suited to the type of question you have.

Comment: Hi umesh; since you have a new account, you might like to read through the [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help). If you find an answer particularly helpful, [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) may be useful information.

Answer (score 3):

data.table package is very useful for such tasks. You can get both mean and SD in one go. Assuming your data.frame is ddf:

```
> ddt = data.table(ddf)
> ddt[,list(mean=mean(Chlorophyll), sd=sd(Chlorophyll)),by=list(Treatment, Stage)]
   Treatment Stage      mean        sd
1:      Salt Green 0.3000000 0.1000000
2:      Salt  Pink 0.3333333 0.1527525
3:      Salt   Red 0.6000000 0.1000000
4:  Nitrogen Green 0.6333333 0.2516611
5:  Nitrogen  Pink 0.3333333 0.1527525
6:  Nitrogen   Red 0.3000000 0.1000000
7:   Control Green 0.6333333 0.1527525
8:   Control  Pink 0.5000000 0.1000000
9:   Control   Red 0.2000000 0.1000000
```

Looking forward to your approach to displaying and analyzing this data.